# From an Application Server to Spring Boot - How Tos for Performance Tuning

Tags: spring-boot, performance, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Currently we have Java applications deployed in an Application server (Websphere to be exact). To fix common performance and memory related problems we encounter, we do tweakings like:

1. Adjust the thread pool setting - to prevent waiting threads.
2. Adjust the application server's garbage collection behavior.

Now, there is a plan to move them to containers (via Docker and using Spring Boot). So essentially they would be converted to Spring boot apps running on Docker containers. Now my question is, what is the equivalent of doing #1 and #2 in this kind of setup? is there still a way to adjust thread pool and garbage collection? or is it a different way now? or this shouldn't be an issue because docker swarm can manage all this and scale?

Edit: for the meantime, docker swarm will be used for managing containers. Kubernetes is still not in the picture.